# how to define a member function of template class which return a nested class object

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-c++, inner-classes

```
template<typename IPC_TYPE>
class Poller
{
private:

public:
    struct Event
    {
        std::shared_ptr<IPC> ipc;
        enum Status
        {
            NONE = 0, POLLIN = 1, POLLHUP = 2, MessageArrival = 3
        }status;
    };

    //block wait
    Event wait(size_t max_wait_time = 50);
};

 template<typename IPC_TYPE>
    Poller<IPC_TYPE>::Event Poller<IPC_TYPE>::wait(size_t max_wait_time = 50)
    {
        Event e;
        return Event();
    }
```

I define a class template `Poller` and also a nested class `Event`, I am writing a member function of `Poller` which return a `Event` object,but the compiler reports **"
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'Event'    IPC poller.cpp  8
"**, how should I do? thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `Poller<IPC_TYPE>::Event`?

Comment: yeah,failed either

Comment: generally the problem is with circular dependency. make sure your header files doesn't include each other

Comment: How about `typename Poller<IPC_TYPE>::Event`?

Comment: I would really need to see the decleration of Event as well... It need to exist outside the private scope of a class, or if it exists in the public space of a class the class name will always be part of the type name, such as Poller<IPC_TYPE>::Event

Comment: The compiler can't find the definition of Event, so please post your header file

Comment: Inside of your class's struct, is it supposed to be `std::shared_ptr<IPC> ipc;` or should it be `std::shared_ptr<IPC_TYPE> ipc;`?

Comment: What is `IPC`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your current code:

> ```
> template<typename IPC_TYPE>
> class Poller {    
> public:
>     struct Event {
>         std::shared_ptr<IPC> ipc;
>         enum Status
>         {
>             NONE = 0, POLLIN = 1, POLLHUP = 2, MessageArrival = 3
>         } status;
>     };
>
>     //block wait
>     Event wait(size_t max_wait_time = 50);
> };
>
> template<typename IPC_TYPE>
> Poller<IPC_TYPE>::Event Poller<IPC_TYPE>::wait(size_t max_wait_time = 50) {
>     Event e;
>     return Event();
> }
> ```

---

I noticed a few issues of concern:

- 1) `std::shared_ptr<IPC> ipc;` I believe should be `std::shared_ptr<IPC_TYPE> ipc;`
- 2) Already been answered by `user:Hiroki` -- `typename` needs to be used before `Poller<IPC_TYPE>::Event` to declare a typename so that the compiler knows how to recognize your intended use. Refer to his answer for a more detailed description and a fuller explanation of why you need `typename`.
- 3) Since you are declaring the function outside of the super class's body, `MSVS 2017 CE` gives a compiler error about having a default value. (See Below).
- 4) Not sure if you are creating a temporary... Then creating and return an instance by its constructor or if the `template argument` will be some kind of `functor` or `function pointer` that you are invoking.
- 5) You have a `std::shared_ptr<IPC_TYPE>` member within `Event` but did not see any dynamic memory being created for type `IPC_TYPE`. So I added a user defined default constructor that set's this in order to see the object's constructors, destructors, operators, member functions, etc. being called, created and destroyed properly.

---

*(3) - Compiler Error:*

```
1>------ Build started: Project: StackQA, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c:\users\...\main.cpp(41): error C5037: 'Poller<IPC_TYPE>::wait': an out-of-line definition of a member of a class template cannot have default arguments
1>Done building project "StackQA.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

There are 2 ways of fixing the above compiler error:

- A) Removing the default value that is in definition that is outside of the super class.
- B) Writing the body of the function within the inner class. If you decide to choose this method of writing your function body; it will actually eliminate the whole need and purpose of your question in the first place since you would be defining it within the inner class.

---

Here is a working example of your class above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <memory>

// Classes A & B are just basic classes with ctor & dtor displaying a message
class A {
public:
    A() { std::cout << "A CTOR called\n"; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "A DTOR called\n"; }
};

class B {
public:
    B() { std::cout << "B CTOR called\n"; }
    ~B() { std::cout << "B DTOR called\n"; }
};

// Classes C & D are functors where their operator invokes a message to be displayed
class C {
public:
    void operator()() { std::cout << "Functor C called\n"; }
};

class D {
public:
    void operator()() { std::cout << "Functor D called\n"; }
};

template <typename IPC_TYPE>
class Poller {
public:
    struct Event {
        std::shared_ptr<IPC_TYPE> ipc; // Made correction here from IPC to IPC_TYPE
        enum Status {
            NONE = 0,
            POLLIN = 1,
            POLLHUP = 2,
            MESSAGE_ARRIVAL = 3, // Changed to All Caps... (personal preference)
        } status;

            // Added this constructor to actually make a shared_ptr of IPC_TYPE
        Event() {
            ipc = std::make_shared<IPC_TYPE>();
        }    
    };

    // Defined the function body within the inner class which also prevents your compiler error.
    Event wait( size_t max_wait_time = 50 ) {
        // Not sure of your intentions here, but for demonstration purposes
        // I've just commented out the temporary and just returned the ctor
        // Event e;
        return Event();
    }
};

// To define it outside of class remove the body from the inner class above,
// uncomment this section, and don't forget to use `typename`.
// Also make sure that your parameter does not have a default value here.
/*template<typename IPC_TYPE>
typename Poller<IPC_TYPE>::Event Poller<IPC_TYPE>::wait( size_t wait_time ) {
    // Not sure of your intentions here, but for demonstration purposes
    // I've just commented out the temporary and just returned the ctor
    //Event e;
    return Event();
}
*/    

int main() {
    try {
        Poller<A> p1;
        p1.wait( 10 );

        Poller<B> p2;
        p2.wait( 12 );

        Poller<C> p3;       
        Poller<C>::Event e1 = p3.wait( 7 );
        e1.ipc->operator()();

        Poller<D> p4;
        Poller<D>::Event e2 = p4.wait( 9 );
        e2.ipc->operator()();

    } catch( std::runtime_error& e ) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

> *-Output-*
>
> ```
> A CTOR called
> A DTOR called
> B CTOR called
> B DTOR called
> Functor C called
> Functor D called
> ```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't know whether `Poller<IPC_TYPE>::Event` is a member variable of `Poller<IPC_TYPE>` or a nested type.

Thus we must type `typename` to remove this ambiguity as follows:

[**DEMO is here.**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/goEXt3HPwNxS6adR)

```
template<typename IPC_TYPE>
typename Poller<IPC_TYPE>::Event Poller<IPC_TYPE>::wait(size_t max_wait_time)
{
    Event e;
    return Event();
}
```