# How to implement a member function outside the generic class that returns an embedded type?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to simulate `class vector` and its `iterator` so this is the problem:

```
template<class T>
class vec {
    public:
        vec();
    vec(const int);
    virtual ~vec();

    T* getElem()const;
    const int size()const;

    void resize(const int);
    void print()const;

    T& operator[](int);


    struct iterator {
        T* elem;
        iterator* operator++();
    };

    iterator begin();
    iterator end();

private:
    T* elem;
    int sz;
};
```

Now I need to implement `iterator begin();` outside the class `vec`:

```
template<class T>
 vec<T>::iterator vec<T>::begin() {

    vec<T>::iterator tmp;
    tmp.elem = elem;

    return tmp;
}
```

And I get the warning:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File Line 
Warning C4346   iterator': dependent name is not a type.
```

And an error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'iterator'.
```

Comment: To use C++ you need to be a good speller, and always use either "ierat" or "iterat", but not both. Spelling is crucial, when it comes to C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I didn't get what you mean?

Comment: It means that your original question spelled the class as `ierat` in one place and `iterat` in the other case. Unfortunately computers aren't smart enough to recognize typos and fix it themselves. It's up to carbon-based life-forms to make sure that everything is spelled correctly all the time. I think I briefly saw that typo corrected but reverted because of a colliding question edit. So, either the current version of the question is correct, and you need to fix your spelling; or the shown code is not the real code with the error, but manually typed-in fake code. Wondering which is the case.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: That is because the class is a bit big thus I wrote it manually which contains some spell mistakes. But no it is edited.

Comment: Best to just spell it out 'iterator' - it is what every one else is used to seeing and they will know exactly what you mean: A forward non-const iterator.

Comment: @natersoz: Ok I edited it now as you suggested.

Comment: Please don't keep editing the question.

Comment: You need to use `typename` outside of a `class Template` that uses a nested class or struct to declare it a type!

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `typename` this way:

```
template<class T>
typename vec<T>::iterator vec<T>::begin() { // typename here is necessary

    iteraror tmp;
    tmp.elem = elem;

    return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your compiler errors explains exactly what is happening:

> And I get the warning:
>
> ```
> Severity    Code    Description Project File Line 
> Warning C4346   iterator': dependent name is not a type.
> ```
>
> And an error:
>
> ```
> Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
> Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'iterator'.
> ```

---

The compiler doesn't know whether `vec<T>::iterator` is a `member variable` of `vec<T>` or a `nested type`.

We must use `typename` to remove this ambiguity as user `Raindrop7` has shown in their answer. They showed you how to fix your compiler error where I've explained why you are getting it.

Without `typename` the code will generate ambiguous code!

With the function outside of the class being as is:

> ```
> template<class T>
> vec<T>::iterator vec<T>::begin() {
>
>     vec<T>::iterator tmp;
>     tmp.elem = elem;
>
>     return tmp;
> }
> ```

Here is why it is producing ambiguity:

Did you mean:

> ```
> vec<t>::iterator as in
>
> template<typename T>
> class vec {
> public:
>     T iterator; 
> };
> ```
>
> Or
>
> ```
> vec<t>::iterator as in 
>
> template<typename T>
> class vec { 
> public:
>     struct iterator { 
>     }; 
> };
> ```

Due to the fact that `iterator` is a `class` or `struct` you must `define` it as a `type`, and this is where `typename` comes into play. This allows the compiler to resolve the `ambiguity` by giving the compiler a hint that `iterator` is a `type` and not a `member`. Thus it will force the compiler to use this:

```
template<typename T>
class vec {
public:
    struct iterator {
    };
};
```

instead of this:

```
template<typename T>
class vec {
public:
    T iterator;
};
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53357852/1757805) is another `Q/A` that would have produced a similar compiler error.